# php getting metadata

Tags: php, metadata

i am trying to extract meta data of a website using the following code
ive changed my code a little

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$domain='http://www.yahoo.com';
?>

<h3>Reading the meta-data tags of website: <?php echo $domain; ?></h3>

<?php 

  echo 'Read META info<br>';
  $tags = get_meta_tags($domain);

  echo 'Check the result and display it.<br>';

  if(isset($tags))
      echo 'Tags is set';

  if (sizeof($tags) == 0){
    echo '<tr><td>No META information was found!</td></tr>';
  }
  else
  {
  echo 'Metadata found !!';
  print_r($tags);
  }

?>
```

But im not getting any result. I am running this script of my local WAMP server. Where am i going wrong? just looking to find very basic information about a page.

this is the result im getting
"Reading the meta-data tags of website: http://www.yahoo.com
Read META info
Check the result and display it.
Tags is setMetadata found !!"

but no output from the print_r($tags)

Comment: Try a print_r($tags); to begin with.

Comment: i used it... no result just the echo statements.

Comment: See if you get any data at all from remote hosts by using file_get_contents('http://yahoo.com'); Perhaps you have some kind of firewall.

Answer (score 1):

for me it works fine. Maybe you don't have curl enabled ? Can you provide us your phpinfo output?

Just create `phpinfo.php` file with the following code inside:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

If there will be no word about curl, you need to open your php.ini file, find the `;extension=php_curl.dll` line and uncomment it (by removing the `;` char)

then restart your apache

Comment: there is even an easiest way to check if curl is enabled. In the same file, replace `phpinfo()` with `var_dump(curl_version())`. If there will be some errors, it means that you don't have it enabled :)

Comment: curl was not enabled, so i enabled it but still no result, i also tried print_r($tags);  but still no result :/

Comment: please add a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` line at the beginning of your file (just after `<?php`) and check if there are no errors

Comment: oh, and have you restarted apache?

Comment: ive done all of that, ive changed the code a bit $tags is getting set and its size is greater than 0 but no output :(

Comment: so please check your apache log file, there should be some info about this problem

Comment: [Mon Mar 14 15:08:58 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 14 15:08:58 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 24 2010 13:33:15
[Mon Mar 14 15:08:58 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 7760
[Mon Mar 14 15:08:58 2011] [notice] Child 7760: Child process is running
[Mon Mar 14 15:08:58 2011] [notice] Child 7760: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Mar 14 15:08:58 2011] [notice] Child 7760: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Mar 14 15:08:58 2011] [notice] Child 7760: Starting thread to listen on port 80.

Comment: and these are the last lines of this file? Can you post a bit more on http://pastebin.com ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine, try to debug row-by-row using `print_r($tags)` .
Anyway if it reads well, then you should be able to get for example the keywords like this:

```
$kws = explode(",",$meta['keywords']);
for ($i=0;$i<count($kws);$i++)
{
    $kws[$i] = ltrim($kws[$i]);
    $kws[$i] = rtrim($kws[$i]);
    echo($kws[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For yahoo.com and google.com you will not get any meta tags. I also tried but i don't know why, may be this sites works as search engine.

```
<?php
 $tags = get_meta_tags('http://sitename.com/');

 echo $tags['keywords'];    
 echo $tags['description'];  
?>
```

This code works for other sites in which meta tags are mentioned.